# How to install and configure Tomcat for eclipse IDE in macOS?

Tags: macos, apache, eclipse

Yes I know there are various similar questions like.

> [eclipse how to configure tomcat that install from package manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909592/eclipse-how-to-configure-tomcat-that-install-from-package-manager)

but not finding any solution to the problem I am facing.
**What I am trying to do:**

- Install Eclipse on macOS
- Install Tomcat 8/8.5 on same machine
- Configure Tomcat to test Servlet developed in eclipse

**What I have done so far:** 
1. Installed Eclipse
2. Installed tomcat using `brew install tomcat@8` :**nothing else done** 
3. Tried adding Server in Eclipse with path : `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8`

Comment: why @8 rather than brew install tomcat only ? If I am not wrong this will install the latest one and 8 is the latest version, isn't it ?

Comment: @Udhy latest is 10(Alpha), I am a student and I have been assigned this task to be specifically done using 8

Comment: okay. Then did you check this way: https://crunchify.com/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-and-install-apache-tomcat-server-in-eclipse-development-environment-ide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 01 :Download Files Required

First Download the Version you Need for your project.
Make sure you download **Core zip file from the link below:**

- Download Apache 7 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).
- Download Apache 8 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).
- Download Apache 9 Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi).
- Download Apache 10 (Alpha) Tomcat from [this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi).
  [image]

  > Select .Zip from above section
  >   Once you have downloaded it, unzip it to a location

### Step 02 :Setting up Server in Eclipse

- Open Eclipse Environment
- Click on Servers Tab
- Click on No servers are available. Click this link to create a new server...
- Click Tomcat v(your downloaded version) Server **and Next**
- Choose the extracted folder as path and runtime.
- **DONE!**

Answer (score 3):

You're close. I download packages through Homebrew as well. You need to give it the path all the way down to `libexec`.

So for the tomcat installation directory give it: `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@8/8.5.57/libexec`

The full steps are:

1. Download your Tomcat version through `brew`
2. Eclipse > Preferences
3. On the left click the 'Server' dropdown > Runtime Environments
4. Add
5. For installation directory enter `/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@<version>/<version>/libexec`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I needed.